# What is the difference between php.ini and .user.ini in each folder?

Tags: php

I am trying to understand the difference between the php.ini and .user.ini in each folder. I read this document https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php but still not very clear about that.

If I am understanding properly, php.ini under a folder, such as /home/alan/public_html/ will affect all subfolders such as /home/alan/public_html/test/. But .user.ini under /home/alan/public_html/ will only affect this folder, not its subfolders, is that correct?

**Update**

I am using cPanel MultiPHP Editor and check this doc https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/software/multiphp-ini-editor-for-cpanel/. It said "The Basic Mode section of this interface loads directive values from the **php.ini file for your selected domain or home directory**. Make your changes to the desired directives and click Apply. The system saves changes to the **php.ini file, the user.ini file, and your .htaccess** file.

So it seems both php.ini and user.ini can be folder specific.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one `php.ini` file that affects all PHP scripts.

You can have custom .ini files with a default filename `.user.ini` but changeable using the [`user_ini.filename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.user-ini.filename) option in your main `php.ini` file that can have overrides to the main `php.ini`. **PHP will not read more than one `php.ini` file**. What can be overridden are directives that are flagged as `PHP_INI_PERDIR` and `PHP_INI_USER` in [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

Any `.user.ini` file will affect the folder it is in and all subfolders. This only happens when using `php-fpm` the the PHP FastCGI module i.e. if you're not using `php-fpm` then any `.user.ini` files have no effect.

If you plan to use `.user.ini` configuration also read https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php#124175 on how to protect it from being accessed

Comment: Thank you. My system using cPanel MultiPHP Manager and it seems that under many folders, there are both php.ini and .user.ini

Comment: This sounds like cPanel specific. It might be switching the default `php.ini` that is read based on the request. I don't know anything about that. At any rate `phpinfo()` should always say which is the `php.ini` file that has been read along with any additional configuration files read